# InvokeMember call is throwing MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am invoking one of the functions from assembly but I am getting MissingMethodException.  I have open exe in .netreflector and show that function is available at right place though it is giving error. Here is the code.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Assembly obj = Assembly.LoadFrom("Solo4O.exe");
        Type datacrypt = obj.GetType("Orch.DC");

        object[] objects = new object[3];
```

....

```
        datacrypt.InvokeMember("GetCryptedXML", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
                                                BindingFlags.Static |
                                                BindingFlags.Public,
                               null, datacrypt, objects, null);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `target` argument is `datacrypt` but it should be `null`, as you're calling a static method (and you're definitely not calling a method *on* `datacrypt`).

Beyond that, it's hard to know exactly what's wrong, partly because you haven't shown how you've initialized `objects`... we don't know what the types involved are. Please show more code. I strongly suspect that one of your argument types is invalid for the method call.

Comment: @Akie: And how big is the `objects` array? It would really help if you could come up with a short but compelte program which demonstrates the problem...

Comment: @Akie: Please edit your question, using full formatting, rather than writing in comments. Also make sure you've actually given all the required code - I want to be able to build and run the code you provide. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @Akie: Did you read the link I sent you? The code you've given still won't compile without me performing a bunch of changes...

Comment: Solved.. Problem was third argument of called function. I had declared it in my project and I was passing it explicitly instead of creating it dynamically. Hence, it was not able to find function with correct match of arguments. I have created third argument by calling GetField. Anyways, thanks for your reply Jon.